# PostgreSQL : "ALTER SCHEMA schema_name OWNER TO role_name" is stuck

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking, access-rights

In my case it is required to change owner for schema in PostgreSQL database, I used statement:

```
ALTER SCHEMA schema_name OWNER TO role_name
```

but the statement is running and running and running... During the day re-started it at least twice after more than 3 hours running time.
Looks like something is locked and it is preventing statement finishing. However after several queries to `pg_locks/pg_class/pg_namespace` I didnt find anything that would be a reason for the lock.

Please, share you expirience how to manage/investigate such cases.

Comment: Check the result from pg_stat_activity, some query should be there, blocking yours.

Comment: Thanks for idea, will take it into account in the future. For now the case is resolved : once one of my collegue switched off his PC then my statement finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For now the case is resolved : once one of my collegue switched off his PC then my statement finished successfully.